# SQL - one item per row

Tags: sql, unpivot

I have a table called Registers, containing 3 fields as below :

```
Select PersonID, RegisterID, Status from Registers

PersonID    RegisterID  Status
-------------------------------
3049518     14467       A
3049518     14467       B
3049518     14467       C
3049518     32445       A
3049518     32445       B
3049518     32445       C
```

Is there a simple way to show each register on single line, along with its status? eg

```
PersonID    RegisterID  Status1 Status2 Status3
------------------------------------------------
3049518     14467       A       B       C
3049518     32445       A       B       C
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the list of values in the `Status` column pre-determined and unchanging, or is it totally dynamic?  This will change the complexity of the answer signficantly.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: How do you know which status is 1, 2, or 3?  What if there is a fourth status?

Comment: Please define `Status`?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT   ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR , Status)       
                                                            FROM DBO.Registers WITH (NOLOCK)

                                                            FOR XML PATH('')),2,20000)),'')
```

or else provide sql fiddle so that I write complete query

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed number of statuses and you know the status values then you can get what you're after using the following code.

```
CREATE TABLE #Register(PersonID int, RegisterID int, Stat varchar)

INSERT INTO #Register (PersonID,RegisterID,Stat) VALUES
('3049518','14467','A'),
('3049518','14467','B'),
('3049518','14467','C'),
('3049518','32445','A'),
('3049518','32445','B'),
('3049518','32445','C')

SELECT PersonID
    ,RegisterID
    ,MAX(A) 'A'
    ,MAX(B) 'B'
    ,MAX(C) 'C'
FROM (
    SELECT PersonID
        ,RegisterID
        ,CAST(CASE 
                WHEN r.stat = 'A'
                    THEN 'A'
                ELSE NULL
                END AS VARCHAR) AS 'A'
        ,CAST(CASE 
                WHEN r.stat = 'B'
                    THEN 'B'
                ELSE NULL
                END AS VARCHAR) AS 'B'
        ,CAST(CASE 
                WHEN r.stat = 'C'
                    THEN 'C'
                ELSE NULL
                END AS VARCHAR) AS 'C'
    FROM #Register r
    GROUP BY PersonID
        ,RegisterID
        ,Stat
    ) q
GROUP BY q.PersonID
    ,q.RegisterID
```

The code assumes there is one record per person per status.

It outputs

[image: code result]

If the status values are not fixed and you don't know what they are you can use the following in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE #Register(PersonID int, RegisterID int, Stat varchar)

INSERT INTO #Register (PersonID,RegisterID,Stat) VALUES
('3049518','14467','A'),
('3049518','14467','B'),
('3049518','14467','C'),
('3049518','32445','A'),
('3049518','32445','B'),
('3049518','32445','C')


DECLARE @queryPart1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@queryPart2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@colHeader NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @queryPart1 = 'SELECT PersonID,RegisterID'
SET @queryPart2 = 'FROM (SELECT PersonID,RegisterID'
SET @query = ''

DECLARE Stat_Cursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT DISTINCT (STAT)
FROM #Register r

OPEN Stat_Cursor;

FETCH NEXT
FROM Stat_Cursor
INTO @colHeader

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @queryPart1 = @queryPart1 + ',MAX(''' + @colHeader + ''') ''' + @colHeader + ''''
    SET @queryPart2 = @queryPart2 + ',CAST(CASE WHEN r.stat = ''' + @colHeader + ''' THEN ''' + @colHeader + ''' ELSE NULL END AS VARCHAR) AS ''' + @colHeader + ''''

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM Stat_Cursor
    INTO @colHeader
END;

CLOSE Stat_Cursor;

DEALLOCATE Stat_Cursor;

SET @query = @queryPart1 + @queryPart2 + 'FROM #Register r GROUP BY PersonID ,RegisterID,Stat) q'

PRINT @query
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if you use Oracle:

```
    select * from ( 
    select PersonID,RegisterID, Status
   from test t
)
pivot 
(
   count(Status)
   for Status in ('A' as "Status1",'B' "Status2",'C' "Status3")
)
order by 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9f6b/5)

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying. 
Sorry, I should have said - I am using SQL Server 2008 R2
The STATUS values are fixed, there are only 3 of them (A,B,C)
The meaning of STATUS : A = Present, B = Absent, C = Late

Comment: @Jim just seen this comment however I have added a dynamic version of the query below.